# how to display in html, the image is /var/www/, but the html is in /var/www/site/teste/index.html

Tags: image, web, var

the html is in /var/www/site/teste/index.html.
I tried 
`<img src = '/var/www/img.jpg' />`,
`<Img src ='../../var/www/img.jpg' />`,

Answer (score 0):

You should write:
    You shoul write: `<Img src ='../../img.jpg' />`